# How to add a coordinate after add layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system

how can i edit a layer that already out of the coordinate? (example: already setting blank layer with appropriate coordinate, but when added a new layer, it look like there is negative coordinate...) can some explain to me how to solve this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinate reference system may need to be set the same on both layers.

Right click and set layer crs. check they match. if not it may need to be a user defined crs.

Comment: and the crs stand for....i am quite new to this. so a little bit slow about the term use...

Comment: coordinate reference system. it is called different things in different programs. but in qgis its crs. it is the basic referencing behind the location of points and lines.